# How to convert this into styled-components and how to nest classes

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I'm starting with css-in-js using styled-components as the main library, and I have 2 problems.

First problem, how do I nest classes?

```css
footer{
  color: red;
}

footer p{
  padding: 16px 8px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
  <footer>
    <div className="container">
      <p>&copy; 1997-2015,All rights reserved.</p>
    </div>
  </footer>
```

My second problem is, I have a div which use 2 classes, one in **container** from bootstrap and another is a my own custom class, and I don't know how to concatenate this 2 classes in styled-components.

Comment: Nesting classes is built into styled-components. No need to use any kind of preprocessor!

Comment: This might help you with [jss]: http://cssinjs.org/jss-compose?v=v5.0.0

Answer (score 4):

```
const MyStyledComponent = styled.footer`
  & > div {
    color: red;
  }

  & > div > p {
    padding: 16px 8px;
    font-size: 30px;
  }
`;
```

Think of & as a "this element".

---

There are 2 ways to add classes to Styled Component. One is just simply add className property

```
<StyledComponent className="container my-class" />
```

or if you want to use these classes in every place in your application you can set defaults class for it by setting attribute for your styled component.

```
const StyledComponent = styled.div.attrs({
 className: 'container my-class',
})`
  color: #f00;
`;
```